# Paypal API - Any paypment method which let the user call the amount?

Tags: php, paypal

I have this question about Paypal's api(not the rEST one - it doesn't support my country, yet).

Users on my site can create campains, and invite friends.
These friends which were invited, will be able to send money, but they need to call the amount.

It is load and clear, I can put an input(text input), and capture the number and send it with my SERVER's API call. This solution is bad for me!!!

My main goal is to send mails with the invitation, so on a simple click i will redirect the user from he's mailbox to the paypal checkout page(credit card form by default). 
Then, He would be able to set the amount he wants to pay, and that's it.

Is there any way to do this with some kind of paypal payment method ?